# Error in Bash when installing Heroku gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, heroku

I successfully installed Heroku(3.99.1) in the terminal but then there was an error message that read:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/doc/excon-0.59.0
```

I then tried to login to Heroku in the terminal and the Heroku CLI was installed. I entered my email and password that I registered on the Heroku website, but another message refers to the same error:

```
MODULE_NOT_FOUND: Cannot find module './lib/request'
```

I have no idea as to the cause of, or the solution to this problem. Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: update ruby in your system

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thanks :-)